# Necesito quitar los 3 puntos del menú en Wordpress uso la plantilla blade

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Necesito quitar esto y he intentado y no se como, necesito la ayuda urgente por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Robbie, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es explicar en detalle lo que te sucede y haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

primero debes buscar en la administración de Wordpress, si te aparece algún método para desactivarlo, si no aparece ya tendrás que entrar en el código y quitarlo a mano y si estas muy apurado puedes buscar que clase o id tiene este elemento en el DOM y entonces ponerle un "display:none;" en su estilo (esto no se recomienda para nada, pero bueno ya digo en caso de que estés muy apurado)

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta el compañero más arriba lo optimo sería buscarlo en las opciones del tema, seguro que está. Si no lo consigues busca su id o clas y lo escondes por CSS.